# Transparent regions of a BufferedImage are writing out black

Tags: java, image, compositing

I know this is something to do with compositing but I can't work out what. In an earlier section of code, a particular list of pixels in a BufferedImage are set to be transparent black:

```
        for(Pixel p : closed){
            Color c = new Color(image.getRGB(p.x, p.y));
            Color newC = new Color(0,0,0, 0);
            image.setRGB(p.x, p.y, newC.getRGB() & 0x00000000);
        }

        if(andCrop){
            image = image.getSubimage(left, top, right-left, bottom-top);
        }


        return image;
```

Then I attempt to write the image out:

```
try {

            BufferedImage out = new BufferedImage(image.getWidth(), image.getHeight(), java.awt.Transparency.TRANSLUCENT);
            Graphics2D g2d = out.createGraphics();
            g2d.setComposite(AlphaComposite.Clear);
            g2d.fillRect(0, 0, image.getWidth(), image.getHeight());
            g2d.setComposite(AlphaComposite.Src);
            g2d.drawImage(image, 0, 0, image.getWidth(), image.getHeight(), null);
            g2d.dispose();

            File outputfile = new File(file);
            ImageIO.write(out, "png", outputfile);
        } catch (IOException e) {

        }
```

Now, I know that 'out' is clear before I attempt to draw the image onto it. What I'm not getting is what's wrong with my compositing. Instead of coming out as transparent, I'm getting full-black.

All bufferedimages used are INT_ARGB.

EDIT - This has been solved. The image source was from ImageIO.read and the BufferedImage returned did not support alpha. A quick post-read conversion let the rest of the code run smoothly.

Comment: For better help sooner, post an [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/).

Comment: BTW - I would use [`BufferedImage.TYPE_INT_ARGB`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/constant-values.html#java.awt.image.BufferedImage.TYPE_INT_ARGB) for the image type  rather than [`Transparency.TRANSLUCENT`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/constant-values.html#java.awt.Transparency.TRANSLUCENT).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Whelp, this has been downvoted now so I'm not sure this will be relevant, but the issue was that **the original BufferedImage was being read in by ImageIO, and this image was not supporting ARGB**. A quick post-read conversion allowed the rest of the code to work.

Answer (score 1):

Things that comes to my mind... (thanks to Andrew):

```
java.awt.Transparency.TRANSLUCENT = 3
TYPE_INT_ARGB = 2
TYPE_INT_ARGB_PRE = 3

public BufferedImage(int width,
                 int height,
                 int imageType)

Constructs a BufferedImage of one of the predefined image types. (TYPE_...)
```

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/awt/image/BufferedImage.html

so it seems as basically it's a mixup.

Besides, what *is* the effect you want to achieve? you clear an empty image, then draw fully transparent pixels to it... I just don't get it.

Comment: I've used ARGB previously - translucent was after some desperate scrabbling. I thought perhaps the initial image needed to be transparent.

Comment: My issues is that I have a BufferedImage which has some - but not all - transparent pixels. The border is transparent, for instance. I need to write it to a file, but when I do so, what were the transparent pixels come out opaque, not transparent.

Comment: uh, there was a typo, in the source there is:     public static final int OPAQUE = 1;
    public static final int BITMASK = 2;
    public static final int TRANSLUCENT = 3; - but the idea was that the value 3 (from TRANSLUCENT, here meaning just ARGB_PRE) is assigned in a bogus way

Comment: Aha, thanks! That's good to know, just generally. I'll switch that back.